# jQuery plugin not separating instances

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

This plugin I am writing is behaving badly. The second instance is clobbering the options set in the first instance. What am I missing to complete the separation so that two copies can be loaded in the same page, with distinct parameeters?

```
;(function($){
    var self;
    var console = window.console;
    var alert = window.alert;

    var TimeSpinner = function(elem, opt) {
        self = this;
        self.elem = elem;
        self.hour = '00';
        self.quarter = '00';
        self.meridian = 'am';
        return self.init(opt);
    };

    TimeSpinner.prototype = {

        init:   function(opt) {

        }
    };


    $.fn.timeSpinner = function(options) {
    if(this.length) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined == $(this).data('timeSpinner')) {
                var rev = new TimeSpinner(this, options);
                $(this).data('timeSpinner', rev);
            }
        });
      }
   };
}(jQuery));

jQuery().ready(function($){
    window.startSpinner = $('#start-spinner').timeSpinner({time: '06:30' });
    window.endSpinner = $('#end-spinner').timeSpinner({time: '12:30' });
});
```

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `self` variable which you have delcared in a shared scope, so every time the constructor is called it will override the value of `self`

```
  var TimeSpinner = function(elem, opt) {
    var self = this;
    self.elem = elem;
    self.hour = '00';
    self.quarter = '00';
    self.meridian = 'am';
    return self.init(opt);
  };
```

Comment: How should I store instance data on the instance, exactly?  Would `this.data.hour = '00';` be discrete from other instances?

Answer (score 0):

`var TimeSpinner = function(elem, opt) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.hour = '00';
        this.quarter = '00';
        this.meridian = 'am';
        return this.init(opt);
    };`

All the TimeSpinner instances will use the same Variable "self";

Why use "self" here?